# SVM for an unbalanced textual dataset?

Tags: svm, text-mining, scikit-learn, kernel-trick

I have a text classification task, currently I can classify the data with very poor precision. This are the scores:

```
Accuracy: 0.461057692308
score: 0.461057692308
precision: 0.212574195636
recall: 0.461057692308
```

And this is how the dataset looks, which is about 2599 documents with 5 categories from 1 to 5:

```
5 1190
4 839
3 239
2 204
1 127
```

How can I improve the above-mentioned results? Is there something like a "kernel" that separate this biased data? What about using more negative bi-grams for balance the dataset?.

Update:

This is the confusion matrix:

```
[[  0   0   0  47   0]
 [  0   0   0  36   0]
 [  0   0   0  64   0]
 [  0   0   0 223   0]
 [  0   0   0 280   0]]
```

I also was reading this [paper](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/specific/congreso/akbani_svm_2004.pdf):

> A popular approach towards solving these problems is to bias the
>   classifier so that it pays more attention to the positive instances.
>   This can be done, for instance, by increasing the penalty associated
>   with misclassifying the positive class relative to the negative class.

Any idea of how to do with scikit-learn?.

Comment: Can you show the confusion matrix?

Comment: Before you go into trying out different approaches, I just want to ask 1] Which kernel are you using? Linear kernel usually is the better choice 2] Did you optimize the C parameter? Optimizing C parameter can make a lot of difference, I can personally attest to a case, where accuracy jumped from 23% to 77% just by optimizing the C parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TenaliRaman, This is the setup of the SVM(SVC):`c=10.0, cache_size=200, class_weitgh=None, coef=0.0, degree=3, gamma=1e-3, kernel=rbf, max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False`

Comment: I tested with several GridSearchs, but that's the problem... I dont figure how to set the parameters, I am using tfidf vectorizer by the way...

Comment: tfidf is a good choice. Set kernel='linear' and check your results. Of course, use GridSearch for C parameter setting. Does your training data have labels in the same proportions as your test data? If so, set class_weight='auto'.

Comment: I tried with a linar kernel and the metrics go down, the same ocurred when I tried increasing the gamma, My data labels are distribuited like this(label-number of instances):5-1190, 4-839, 3-239, 2-204, 1-127, so as you can see the data is more frecuent in class 5 and 4. Thanks!

Comment: did you try class_weight='auto' ?

Comment: Yes, the scores go down: `Accuracy: 0.0723076923077, score: 0.0723076923077, precision: 0.00522840236686, recall: 0.0723076923077`